# Bittorrent: Getting info_hash in erlang while communicating to udp tracker

Tags: erlang, bittorrent

I am trying to write a bittorrent client in erlang (release 20).

How do I get the **info_hash** rightly for communication with udp trackers and peer?
I am using below piece of code right now, but its not working as I am not getting response from tracker.

```
InfoHash = crypto:hash(sha, bencoding:encode(maps:get(<<"info">>, 
DecodedContents))),
```

Do I need to urlencode it?

Answer (score 2):

I figured out my mistake after 2 days.
I had set socket mode to passive and hence I was not getting any message
in the receive block.
Setting back to active solved the issue.

Comment: So now are you getting infohash from DHT nodes and trackers?